# Is there a way to check and repair a GeoPackage GPkg file?

Tags: geoserver, geopackage, maxar-digitalglobe

I have downloaded imagery in GeoPackage format from My DigitalGlobe EV which is used offline on a non-internet connected system. However the GPkg seems to be non-standard.

I'm trying to load the GPkg with GeoServer with the GeoPackage extension. However, when I add a GPkg data store I get a Java exception, which I've filed a bug on.

I've tried using GDAL_translate to convert it to a GeoTIFF, and even convert it from GPkg to a new GPkg, but both cause gdal_translate to hang with 100% CPU usage. GDAL also complains about an invalid 'application_id' in the GPkg file.

Is there a script to repair or rebuild a raster GeoPackage file? Before I contact DigitalGlobe, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What is the number of the GeoServer issue? Conversion from GPKG into GeoTIFF with GDAL fails? I fear that you can't share your GeoPackage file, am I right?

Comment: The GeoServer bug is [GEOS-7166](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7166). Conversion from GPKG to GeoTIFF doesn't fail, but hangs at 0 on the progress display. I can convert the Whitehorse sample GeoPackage without issue. I'm pretty sure the DigitalGlobe license won't let me share files, though I don't think there'd be any harm in posting a tiny patch of ocean imagery for the sake of troubleshooting...

Comment: The actual error in your GeoServer issue is probably `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Envelope must be at least two-dimensional and non-empty.` It may mean that your GeoPackage has wrong metadata and also that without sample data it can be very hard to find the reason for the failure. Perhaps DigitalGlobe folks would be willing to put a sample GPKG into their site.

Answer (score 2):

RGi has just posted its GPKG libraries on GitHub. 
https://github.com/GitHubRGI/swagd
Part of this is a verifier tool which is an executable test suite for the tiles portion of the GPKG specification. It will inform you of any places where a GPKG fails to comply. While this tool has not been officially approved by OGC, the plan is to roll it into an OGC test suite. We did use it as part of the GeoPackage Plugfest last year.

Comment: Keep in mind that the https://github.com/GitHubRGI/swagd *has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.*