# GeoServer GeoPackage plugin fault

Tags: geoserver, epsg, geopackage

I am having difficulty adding a .gpkg raster store to geoserver with the GeoPackage community plugin installed.
I can successfully accomplish .gpkg in and out with EPSG:4326.

Using EPSG:3857 I can only output .gpkg from GeoServer.

Steps to reproduce are simple:

1. add a properly 3857 georeferenced geotiff image as a independent store and layer.
2. export the layer as GeoPackage using the GeoServer web UI. This will generate a valid  3857 gpkg.
3. attempt to add this new GeoServer/GeoPackage generated gpkg as a new store. 
   This fails with same error as : [Is there a way to check and repair a GeoPackage GPkg file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162142/is-there-a-way-to-check-and-repair-a-geopackage-gpkg-file)
   and
   https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7166

I can extract the tiled images into a zoom/column/row.jpg pyramid but I have no idea how to import such a pyramid into GeoServer. 
Is there a simple raster store plugin to grab 3857 tiles from the filesystem?

Comment: Is this with 2.10.0? If not please upgrade and try again. There may be a bug but lots of fixes went into the geotools geopkg module for the last release

Comment: Thank you.
Yes I am using 2.10.x, looking at my install script I am pulling from NIGHTLY. I am going to retry and pull all plugins and binary from a fixed date and retry. I also found that the gdal native libs need to have a specific version I used version 1.1.16

Comment: Same result.
In order to reproduce add this world file and run: 

gdal_translate -outsize 256 256 -a_srs EPSG:3857 -of GTiff <inFile> <tmpFile>.tiff

geotifcp -e <worldFile> <tmpFile>.tiff <outFile>.geotiff


world file of mercator NW quadrant
<snip>

78271.516964

0

0

-78271.516964

-19998372.584307

19998372.584307

</snip>

Comment: There are two issues I identified.

Comment: 1. EPSG:3857 failed in org.geotools.geopkg.mosaic.GeoPackageReader. This needed to be hacked to set worldSpan to 2* 20037508.342789 and both x and y offset to -20037508.342789 when dealing with EPSG:3857  
mvn package  
then copy resulting jar to geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/  
2. I needed to relayer the vertical tile numbers in my gpkg file with 
  sqlite3 ${db} "UPDATE ${tiles} SET tile_row=15-tile_row WHERE zoom_level=4"  
you need to change the 15 to 2^zoom-1 for each zoom_level

Comment: Looks like you should update the bug report (and potentially submit a pull request). See geoserver.org for the links you need.